# SpeakEasy security with secret exposed

Tags: node.js, speakeasy

I was using the speakeasy package to implement google auth in my app. After generating the  secret as below.

```
var secret = speakeasy.generateSecret({
      name: `***`
      // encoding: 'ascii'
    });
```

I would then validate like below:

```
let validOtp = speakeasy.totp.verify({
              secret: `***`,
              encoding: 'ascii',
              token: code
            });
```

If the secret generated was compromised, would it be possible to bypass this verification even without having the timebased otp or is this still secure?

I thought it would be better to encrypt the secret then decrypt when needed. Is this overkill and unnecessary?

Save

Answer (score 0):

I found my answer in a github issues thread. As soon as the secret key is compromised, the attacker can generate a code at any point.

https://github.com/speakeasyjs/speakeasy/issues/24